# Optimal way to use AWS S3 for a backend application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In order to learn how to connect backend to AWS, I am writing a simple notepad application. On the frontend it uses Editor.js as an alternative to traditional WYSIWYG. I am wondering how best to synchronise the images uploaded by a user.

To upload images from disk, I use the following plugin: https://github.com/editor-js/image

In the configuration of the tool, I give the api endpoint of the server to upload the image. The server in response have to send the url to the saved file. My server saves the data to s3 and returns the link.

But what if someone for example adds and removes the same file over and over again? Each time, there will be a new request to aws.

And here is the main part of the question, should I optimize it somehow in practice? I'm thinking of saving the files temporarily on my server first, and only doing a synchronization with aws from time to time. How this is done in practice? I would be very grateful if you could share with me any tips or resources that I may have missed.

I am sorry for possible mistakes in my English, i do my best.

Thank you for help!

Comment: How do ppl upload these images? Do they have to authenticate somehow to your app? If not, then allowing anonymous uploads of images to your AWS account is not a good idea, and have to be carefully think through.

Comment: Yes, each user has an account and must be logged in. On top of that I have other safeguards like a request limit.

Comment: If you have request limits then and you know exactly what each user uploads, then you can easy check how many times a given user upload an image. Its something you have to implement in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should **upload them to S3 as soon as** they are available. This way you are ensuring their availability and resistance to failure of you instance. S3 store files across multiple availability zones (AZs) ensuring reliable long-term storage. On the other hand, an instance operates only within one AZ and if something happens to it, all your data on the instance is lost. So potentially you can lost entire batch of images if you wait with the uploads.

In addition to that, S3 has virtually **unlimited capacity**, so you are not risking any storage shortage. When you keep them in batches on an instance, depending on the image sizes, there may be a scenario where you simply run out of space.

Finally, the good practice of developing apps on AWS is to make them **stateless**. This means that your instances should be considered disposable and interchangeable at any time. This is achieved by not storing any user data on the instances. This enables you to auto-scale your application and makes it fault tolerant.